# Split string by count of characters

Tags: python, string

I can't figure out how to do this with string methods:

In my file I have something like 1.012345e0070.123414e-004-0.1234567891.21423... which means there is no delimiter between the numbers.

Now if I read a line from this file I get a string like above which I want to split after e.g. 12 characters. 
There is no way to do this with something  like `str.split()` or any other string method as far as I've seen but maybe I'm overlooking something?

Thx

Comment: maybe duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python

Comment: Funny: the answer I put here is almost verbatim the answer I put there...

Answer (score 35):

Since you want to iterate in an unusual way, a generator is a good way to abstract that:

```
def chunks(s, n):
    """Produce `n`-character chunks from `s`."""
    for start in range(0, len(s), n):
        yield s[start:start+n]

nums = "1.012345e0070.123414e-004-0.1234567891.21423"
for chunk in chunks(nums, 12):
    print chunk
```

produces:

```
1.012345e007
0.123414e-00
4-0.12345678
91.21423
```

(which doesn't look right, but those are the 12-char chunks)

Answer (score 19):

You're looking for [string slicing.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

```
>>> x = "1.012345e0070.123414e-004-0.1234567891.21423"
>>> x[2:10]
'012345e0'
```

Answer (score 8):

```
line = "1.012345e0070.123414e-004-0.1234567891.21423"
firstNumber = line[:12]
restOfLine = line[12:]

print firstNumber
print restOfLine
```

**Output**:

```
1.012345e007
0.123414e-004-0.1234567891.21423
```

Answer (score 6):

you can do it like this:

```
step = 12
for i in range(0, len(string), 12):
    slice = string[i:step]
    step += 12
```

in this way on each iteration you will get one slice of 14 characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(n, iterable, padvalue=None):
    return izip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*n, fillvalue=padvalue)
```

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled on this while looking for a solution for a similar problem - but in my case I wanted to split string into chunks of differing lengths. Eventually I solved it with RE

```
In [13]: import re

In [14]: random_val = '07eb8010e539e2621cb100e4f33a2ff9'

In [15]: dashmap=(8, 4, 4, 4, 12)

In [16]: re.findall(''.join('(\S{{{}}})'.format(l) for l in dashmap), random_val)
Out[16]: [('07eb8010', 'e539', 'e262', '1cb1', '00e4f33a2ff9')]
```

**Bonus**

For those who may find it interesting - I tried to create pseudo-random ID by specific rules, so this code is actually part of the following function

```
import re, time, random 
def random_id_from_time_hash(dashmap=(8, 4, 4, 4, 12)):
     random_val = ''
     while len(random_val) < sum(dashmap):
         random_val += '{:016x}'.format(hash(time.time() * random.randint(1, 1000)))
     return '-'.join(re.findall(''.join('(\S{{{}}})'.format(l) for l in dashmap), random_val)[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

I always thought, since string addition operation is possible by a simple logic, may be division should be like this. When divided by a number, it should split by that length. So may be this is what you are looking for.

```
class MyString:
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string
    def __div__(self, div):
        l = []
        for i in range(0, len(self.string), div):
            l.append(self.string[i:i+div])
        return l

>>> m = MyString(s)
>>> m/3
['abc', 'bdb', 'fbf', 'bfb']


>>> m = MyString('abcd')
>>> m/3
['abc', 'd']
```

If you don't want to create an entirely new class, simply use this function that re-wraps the core of the above code,

```
>>> def string_divide(string, div):
       l = []
       for i in range(0, len(string), div):
           l.append(string[i:i+div])
       return l

>>> string_divide('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 15)
['abcdefghijklmno', 'pqrstuvwxyz']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this function:

```
x = "1.012345e0070.123414e-004-0.1234567891.21423"
while len(x)>0:
  v = x[:12]
  print v
  x = x[12:]
```