# count the number of a certain triplet in a file (DNA codon analysis)

Tags: python, shell, bioinformatics

This question is actually for DNA codon analysis, to put it in a simple way, let's say I have a file like this:
atgaaaccaaag...
and I want to count the number of 'aaa' triplet present in this file. Importantly, the triplets start from the very beginning (which means atg,aaa,cca,aag,...) So the result should be 1 instead of 2 'aaa' in this example.
Is there any Python or Shellscript methods to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Can it be assumed that there are no errors in the file, i.e. that each set of three letters will always indicate a valid set?

Comment: Im guessing he is getting FASTA files... they are typically accepted as valid ...

Comment: Related to / possible duplicate of [Split string by count of characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111068/split-string-by-count-of-characters)

Comment: Also related: [What is the most “pythonic” way to iterate over a list in chunks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)

Comment: Yes, I am going to process FASTA files.

Comment: Moved this to a comment... You will find BioPython very helpful: http://biopython.org/wiki/Biopython

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first readin the file

```
with open("some.txt") as f:
    file_data = f.read()
```

then split it into 3's

```
codons = [file_data[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(file_data),3)]
```

then count em

```
print codons.count('aaa')
```

like so

```
>>> my_codons = 'atgaaaccaaag'
>>> codons = [my_codons[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(my_codons),3)]
>>> codons
['atg', 'aaa', 'cca', 'aag']
>>> codons.count('aaa')
1
```

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution is to split the string into 3-character pieces and then count the number of occurrences of "aaa":

```
s = 'atgaaaccaaag'
>>> [s[i : i + 3] for i in xrange(0, len(s), 3)].count('aaa')
1
```

If the string is really long then this solution will chew up some memory unnecessarily creating the list of substrings.

```
s = 'atgaaaccaaag'
>>> sum(s[i : i + 3] == 'aaa' for i in xrange(0, len(s), 3))
1
>>> s = 'aaatttaaacaaagg'
>>> sum(s[i : i + 3] == 'aaa' for i in xrange(0, len(s), 3))
2
```

This uses a generator expression instead of creating a temporary list, so it will be more memory efficient. It takes advantage of the fact that `True == 1`, i.e. `True + True == 2`.

Answer (score 1):

You could first break the string into triples, using something like:

```
def split_by_size(input, length):
    return [input[i:i+length] for i in range(0, len(input), length)]

tripleList = split_by_size(input, length)
```

Then check for "aaa", and sum it up:

```
print sum(filter(lambda x: x == "aaa", tripleList))
```

Answer (score 0):

using a simple shell, assuming your fasta only contains one sequence.

```
grep -v ">"  < input.fa |
tr -d '\n' |
sed 's/\([ATGCatgcNn]\{3,3\}\)/\1#/g' |
tr "#" "\n" |
awk '(length($1)==3)' |
sort |
uniq -c
```