# Write functions counting the DNA sequence of codon " ATG "

Tags: python

the content of my tasks are "Write functions counting the DNA sequence of codon " ATG "

I did something like that but I do not know what is wrong with that

```
def seq(dna):
    dna = dna.count("ATG")

print seq("ATGSDSGFAGEFRASFWET")
```

Please help me

Comment: So, are you getting an error, or...?

Comment: You did not indent the function body. Otherwise, you should state as specificly as posslible what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: What is “counting the DNA sequence of codon ‘ATG’” supposed to mean? Count the frequency of the sequence? If so, then you cannot simply use the `count` method, it will give you wrong results because it will count frame-shifted “ATG” (e.g. “CATGTA” would return `1`, even though there’s no in-frame “ATG”).

Comment: @Kevin I only getting "None"

Comment: @KonradRudolph exactly

Comment: Use `return dna.count("ATG")` inside your function to return a value

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/12610184/1288408

Comment: I've written many of these before... you could use a modulo to make sure your sequence is divisible by three and returns codons or amino acids as well in your function.  It's more of a sanity check.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Strip your major string in a array of strings with size 3.

2 - Do an iteration in your array of strings and compare with string "ATG"
        - If the comparison is true, increment in 1 an int auxiliar variable

3 - Display the result of the auxiliar int variable

Comment: That's not gonna work: it is possible that `ATG` starts halfway the first substring: like `CAT GAT`. Furthermore it is inefficient. You can use the *Knuth-Moris-Pratt* algorithm to do this in one linear search.

Comment: of course it is gonna work. There is no sequence of proteins in DNA with less or more than 3 letters.

Comment: I mean nucleoside triphosphate instead of proteins

Comment: yeah I know that. But who says you have *the start of the DNA string*. You do not have to do all this expensive splitting, etc.

Comment: Who said the opposite? He is clearly a begginner, does not make sense to explain Knuth-Moris-Pratt approach or something similar. Just solving his problem at the moment. In the right moment he will face more complex questions.

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing you forgot to add `return`?

```
def seq(dna):
    dna = dna.count("ATG")
    return dna

print seq("ATGSDSGFAGEFRASFWET")
```