# Python - Splitting up a string into a list of paired chars

Tags: python, string, list, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)
>   [Split string by count of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111068/split-string-by-count-of-characters)

I have a string (which is hex), something like:

```
717765717777716571a7202020
```

I need to get it into the format:

```
0x71,0x77,0x65,0x71,0x77,0x77...
```

I'm not sure what the best method would be though

Comment: A string can be accessed just like a normal list, so all of the answers on that question will answer this one too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> s = '717765717777716571a7202020'
>>> ['0x' + s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]
['0x71', '0x77', '0x65', '0x71', '0x77', '0x77', '0x71', '0x65', '0x71', '0xa7', '0x20', '0x20', '0x20']
```

If you want a comma-separated string as the result, you can use the following:

```
>>> ','.join('0x' + s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2))
'0x71,0x77,0x65,0x71,0x77,0x77,0x71,0x65,0x71,0xa7,0x20,0x20,0x20'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

```
s = '717765717777716571a7202020'

print ','.join('0x'+''.join(d) for d in zip( *[iter(s)]*2 ))
```

Output:

```
0x71,0x77,0x65,0x71,0x77,0x77,0x71,0x65,0x71,0xa7,0x20,0x20,0x20
```

Comment: You need to use the same `iter(s)`.  e.g. `si = iter(s); ... zip(si,si)` -- this will give you `0x77,0x11,0x77 ...`

Comment: @mgilson: Right...fixed.